# How can I reassign the <alt>-space keybinding?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> shortcut for Synapse.

I have reassigned the Activate Windows Menu from <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> but cannot still receive an error

> Failed to register hotkey 'activate' with signature 'space'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found how to do it:
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
Open it, then
CompizConfig->general options->key bindings: window menu!
disable it!

Comment: In fact, I'm not sure about your question. but CompizConfig will help